# Encrypting credentials and reusing them securely

Tags: python, security, encryption, cryptography

I'm currently building a website where the users would enter their credentials for another web service that I'm going to scrape to get their data.

I want to make sure that when I save their credentials in my database, I'm using the best encryption possible and the best architecture to ensure the highest level of security.

The first idea that I had in mind was to encrypt the data using an RSA pub key (PBKDF2, PKCS1_OAEP, AES 256bit... ???) and then allowing my scrapping script to use the private key to decrypt the credentials and use them.

- But if my server is hacked, the hacker would have access to both the database and the private key, since it will be kept on my server that runs the scrapping script and hosts the DB. Is there an architecture pattern that solves this ?
- I've read that that there should be a mix of hashing and encryption to enable maximum security but hashing is uni directional and it doesn't fit my use case since I will have to reuse the credentials. If you can advise me with the best encryption cypher/pattern you know it could be awesome.

I'm coding in python and I believe PyCrypto is the go-to library for encryption. (Sorry I have very little knowledge about cryptography so I might be confusing technologies)

Comment: If your server is hacked there's probably not much you can do. Maybe as an additional security you could store the private key in a third server, which you then fetch from the main server only when needed. That will prevent a hacker who simply managed to dump your main server and db to access the data. However, if they are on the server monitoring the Python app there's nothing you can do because they can see the key when you fetch it.

Comment: Thank you @this.lau_, yeah it seems to me that the DB and the private key must be on separate servers. I will explore this possibility.

Comment: I get a bad feeling about this. Please go to the SE.Crypto site and ask the experts there what they think of this plan. But in the mean time, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Comment: Ok, I will do so. Thanks @PM2Ring

Answer (score 0):

Do the encryption and decryption on the second server (encryption server).

Pass the password to the encryption server along with an id for encryption and it returns the encrypted password to store in the DB.

When the password is needed pass the encrypted password to the encryption server for decryption.

Have the encryption server monitor request activity, if an unusual number of requests are received sound an alarm and in extreme cases stop processing requests.

Make the second server very secure. No Internet access, minimal access accounts, 2-factor authentication.

The encryption server becomes a poor-man's HSM (Hardware Encryption Module).

Answer (score -2):

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet 
class Crypt():
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.cipher = Fernet(key)

    def encrypt(self, my_message):
        return self.cipher.encrypt(my_message)

    def decrypt(self, my_message):
        return self.cipher.decrypt(my_message)

    @staticmethod        
    def key_maker():
        return Fernet.generate_key()            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KEY = Crypt.key_maker()
    crypt = Crypt(KEY)
    msg = crypt.encrypt(b'hi')
    msg = crypt,decrypt(msg)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it better and more secure to use this implementation than the one coming from well known libraries like PyCrypto ?

Comment: @mandok No, this is a terrible solution. If encryption is needed use AES.

Comment: @GrigorKolev This encryption method is so insecure it should not be used, it is a variety of a polyalphabetic substitution cipher. There are well known attacks on such ciphers, they have not been secure for over a century.

Comment: Note to future readers: this answer has been completely changed since the last two comments.